# Div tag with SWF content and background image should auto stretch

Tags: html, css

`Div` tag with SWF content and background image should auto stretch so that the height of the background image and the `div` tag change accordingly to the SWF content. And they should not go behind `div` tags that are positioned under them, like the footer for example.
What I would like to achieve can be seen here on [this website](http://www.berzerk-land.com/index.php?cmd=game&gameid=677), where the SWF game loads.
I am quite a beginner in web design and was asked to achieve this, so I am sorry if this actually a stupid question and easily done, I just couldn't find any tutorials or explanations of how it is done.

this is the css of the page: (the div tag in question is  #game )

```css
 * {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

body {
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url(_assets/gray_bcg.png);
 background-repeat: repeat;
 background-x-position: center;
 background-y-position: top;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-color: #ccc;
 margin: 0;
}

#container {
display:block;
width:100%;
}

#wrapper {
height:auto!important;
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
width:918px;
background-image:none;
background-repeat:repeat-y;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
}
#content {
 width: 918px;
}


#header {
 display: block;
 height: 368px;
 width: 914px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-image: url(_assets/1header.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#headerSides {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 734px;
 z-index: -1;
 background-image: url(_assets/1sidebars.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center top;
}

#headerLeft {
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 width: 916px;
 background-image: none;
 margin: 200px 0 0;
 left: 0px;
}

#nav {
float:left;
width:584px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#headerSides #wrapper #header #headerLeft #search {
height:59px;
width:306px;
float:right;
margin:-58px 0 0;
}

#add1 {
 background-image: url(_assets/recatangle_ad_container.png);
 float: left;
 height: 105px;
 width: 746px;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
}

#logo {
 background-image: url(_assets/logo_container.png);
 float: right;
 height: 106px;
 width: 166px;
}

.centered {
display:block;
height:65px;
width:122px;
margin:15% auto 5%;
}

#game {
 background-image: url(_assets/gcont917x605.png);
 height: auto;
 width: 917px;
 margin-top: 110px;
 padding-top: 25px;
 padding-left: 160px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#footer {
 background-image: url(_assets/footer.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 917px;
 clear: both;
 height: 300px;
 float: left;
}
```

and this is the html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link href="games.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="Scripts/swfobject_modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="headerSides">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header">
        <div id="headerLeft">

          <div id="navbar">
            <a href="home.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Home','','_assets/_menu/n_home_over.png',1)">
              <img src="_assets/_menu/n_home.png" alt="Home" width="117" height="60" id="Home" />
            </a>
            <a href="games.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('games','','_assets/_menu/n_games_over.png',1)">
              <img src="_assets/_menu/n_games.png" alt="Games" width="117" height="60" id="games" />
            </a>
            <a href="blog.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('blog','','_assets/_menu/n_blog_over.png',1)">
              <img src="_assets/_menu/n_blog.png" alt="Blog" width="117" height="60" id="blog" />
            </a>
            <a href="forum.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('forum','','_assets/_menu/n_forum_over.png',1)">
              <img src="_assets/_menu/n_forum.png" alt="Forum" width="117" height="60" id="forum" />
            </a>
            <a href="about.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('about','','_assets/_menu/n_about_over.png',1)">
              <img src="_assets/_menu/n_about.png" alt="About" width="117" height="60" id="about" />
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- ends navbar   -->
          <div id="search">
            <img src="_assets/search_bt.png" width="306" height="59" alt="search" />
          </div>
          <!-- ends search   -->

          <div id="add1">
            <img src="_adds/728x90.jpg" alt="add1" width="726" height="88" align="right" />
          </div>
          <!-- ends add1  -->

          <div id="logo">
            <img src="_assets/efLogo.png" width="122" height="65" alt="logo" class="centered" />
          </div>
          <!-- ends logo  -->

          <div id="content">

            <div id="game">
              <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="600" height="400" align="middle" id="FlashID" title="epic boss fighter">
                <param name="movie" value="_games/EpicBossFighter.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
                <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
                <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
                <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
                <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object data="_games/EpicBossFighter.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="600" height="400" align="middle">
                  <!--<![endif]-->
                  <param name="quality" value="high" />
                  <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
                  <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
                  <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
                  <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
                  <div>
                    <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
                    <p>
                      <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" />
                      </a>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
              </object>




            </div>
            <!-- ends game   -->

            <div id="footer"></div>

          </div>
          <!-- ends content   -->
        </div>
        <!-- ends headerleft   -->



      </div>
      <!-- ends heADER  -->



    </div>
    <!-- ends wrapper  -->




  </div>
  <!-- ends headerSides  -->



  <script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.registerObject("FlashID");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please, post what you have attempted here on SO so we can help you.

Comment: here is my css and html

Comment: i edited my question and posted the css and the html above